# MySQL delete with nested select query

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I have the following MySQL query:

```
DELETE FROM catalogue 
WHERE catalogue_id IN (
  SELECT catalogue_id 
  FROM catalogue 
  WHERE (
    product_id = (SELECT product_id FROM catalogue WHERE catalogue_id = '2290') 
    AND length_id = (SELECT length_id FROM catalogue WHERE catalogue_id = '2290') 
    AND gauge_id = (SELECT gauge_id FROM catalogue WHERE catalogue_id = '2290')
  )
)
```

But when I attempt to execute I get the following error message:

> You can't specify target table 'catalogue' for update in FROM clause

Could someone advise on where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Perform double nesting

```
DELETE FROM catalogue 
WHERE catalogue_id IN (SELECT catalogue_id FROM (
  SELECT catalogue_id 
  FROM catalogue 
  WHERE (
    product_id = (SELECT product_id FROM catalogue WHERE catalogue_id = '2290') 
    AND length_id = (SELECT length_id FROM catalogue WHERE catalogue_id = '2290') 
    AND gauge_id = (SELECT gauge_id FROM catalogue WHERE catalogue_id = '2290')
  )) x
)
```

It fools mysql

Comment: Works perfectly zerkms, but what's the reason for having to 'fool' MySQL?

Comment: What about if you have more than one `WHERE` column? i.e. `DELETE FROM catalogue 
WHERE catalogue_id AND catalogue_name IN...`

Comment: @ThreaT: I'm not sure what you're asking about. Multiple predicates may be added with `ADD`, yes.

Comment: How would you change your answer to use `ADD`?

Comment: @ThreaT: ask a separate question then. PS: it's `AND` not `ADD` sorry :-)

Comment: It's been 9 years and still need this hackery.

Answer (score 5):

Or you can use temporary table:

```
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t AS
  SELECT catalogue_id 
  FROM catalogue 
  WHERE (
    product_id = (SELECT product_id FROM catalogue WHERE catalogue_id = '2290') 
    AND length_id = (SELECT length_id FROM catalogue WHERE catalogue_id = '2290') 
    AND gauge_id = (SELECT gauge_id FROM catalogue WHERE catalogue_id = '2290')
  );

  DELETE FROM catalogue WHERE catalogue_id IN (SELECT catalogue_id FROM t);
```

With your query you got `You can't specify target table 'catalogue' for update in FROM clause` because you can't make select and update on the same table in one query.

Comment: Thanks Kamil for the explanation.