# MySQL: Deleting table rows from different tables

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to delete a row from a table of MySQL database

### SQL Query:

```
DELETE FROM students WHERE tutor_availability = student_availability;
```

`tutor_availabilty` is contained within another table called `tutors`. Possibly worth noting that I am using xampp. Wondering if anyone could help me with this?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve, can you explain?

Comment: sorry about the vague description, got the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what it is you are actually trying to delete and how your records are related you may want to use and IN instead of a JOIN.  This may also be a little easier to visualize.

For example:

```
DELETE FROM students where student_availability 
IN (Select tutor_availability FROM tutors)
```

Here is a good explanation of JOIN vs IN:

[SQL JOIN vs IN performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200295/sql-join-vs-in-performance)

Comment: I didn't think about the fact that this is in MySQL.  You can use double nesting with a DELETE in MySQL apparently.  Here is an example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298504/mysql-delete-with-nested-select-query

Comment: No I am sorry, I htink this will work as you wrote as it is not the same table. I just confounded the 2 queries... my mistake

Comment: that is the right answer, thank you so much raholling

Answer (score 0):

Didn't get the full picture here, but after reading like 10 times i think you have the following structure

- Table - Stutends (id, student_avaliability, tutor_id...)
- Tutors (id, tutor_avaliability, ... )

So, you may want to try this:

"DELETE FROM students WHERE students.student_availability = tutors.tutor_availability INNER JOIN tutors ON (students.tutor_id = tutors.id)"

Comment: I got the answer, sorry about my vague description. thanks for the help