# While *Delete* the multiple rows using column value, getting "update you can't specify target table for update in from clause" this error in mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm using the below **DELETE** query.

`DELETE FROM tableAA WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM tableAA WHERE coreID IN (SELECT fill_ID FROM tableBBB) and columnData= 'data');`

but I am getting this **"update you can't specify target table for update in from clause"** error.

Comment: Take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298504/mysql-delete-with-nested-select-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this one:

```
DELETE FROM tableAA 
WHERE coreID IN (SELECT fill_ID FROM tableBBB)
  AND columnData = 'data';
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, i can not check my example right now:

```
DELETE FROM tableAA LEFT JOIN tableAA.id = fill_ID.tableBBB WHERE fill_ID NOT IS NULL and columnData = data;
```